# Use Owl Carousel 2 with next.js and react

Tags: jquery, reactjs, next.js, owl-carousel-2

I want to use jQuery owl carousel with my next js react app.
I dont want to use npm package `react-owl-carousel` only `owl-carousel` and `jquery` plugin.

I use lazy load with next.js `dynamic` and put the following code in my Webpack config:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
const Slider = dynamic(() => import('...'), {
  ssr: false,
});
```

Webpack config:

```
config.plugins.push(new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery',
  'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
}));
```

Slider component:

```
import 'owl.carousel';
import 'owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css';
```

When I use `$('element').owlCarousel(...)`, I got the following error:

> TypeError: this.owl.owlCarousel is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after checking the bundle file i find that webpack pass another jQuery instance to owl.carousel file

here is webpack bundle code

```
__webpack_require__(/*! jquery */ "../../node_modules/owl.carousel/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js")
```

as you can see jQuery pass to plugin from `node_modules/owl.carousel/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js` instead of `node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js`

i fixed issue by deleting `node_modules/owl.carousel/node_modules`

after that webpack pass `node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js` as jquery instance

Comment: Thank you so much on the ``ssr:false`` next.js option. That led me to next.js documentation and yes am using react-owl-carousel and works fine now. Been stuck for over 72hrs

Answer (score 4):

In next.config.js:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) => {
config.plugins.push(new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
    }))
return config;
}}
```

In your component:

```
import "owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css";
import "owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.css";
const OwlCarousel = dynamic(import("react-owl-carousel"), {ssr: false});
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Inject global window via jQuery and webpack inside next.config.js file at the root of your next.js project

   ```
        module.exports = {
           webpack: (config, {
               buildId,
               dev,
               isServer,
               defaultLoaders,
               webpack
           }) => {
               // Note: we provide webpack above so you should not `require` it
               // Perform customizations to webpack config
               config.plugins.push(
                   new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                       $: "jquery",
                       jQuery: "jquery",
                       "window.jQuery": "jquery"
                   })
               );
               // Important: return the modified config
               return config;
           }
   ```
2. Slider component which uses `react-owl-carousel` component

   ```
       import OwlCarousel from "react-owl-carousel";

       export default function MySlider({ sliders }) {
         return (
           <section>
               <OwlCarousel
                 loop={true}
                 items={1}
                 responsiveRefreshRate={0}
                 autoplay={true}
                 autoplayTimeout={7000}
                 autoplayHoverPause={true}
                 nav={true}
                 navText={[
                   "<i class='icon-arrow-prev'></i>",
                   "<i class='icon-arrow-next'></i>"
                 ]}
                 dots={false}
                 margin={20}
               >
                 <div class="item"></div>
                 <div class="item"></div>
               </OwlCarousel>
           </section>
         );
       }
   ```
3. Import the component and for use onto your parent component. Kindly note you MUST use the `ssr:false` option. Next.js documentation recommends it

   ```
   const MySlider = dynamic(
     () => import("./Myslider"),
     // No need for SSR, when the module includes a library that only works in the
     // browser.
     { ssr: false }
   );
   ```

Happy codding.